# "Invalid Host Header" in When running React App

Tags: reactjs, deployment, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am having one simple project of React JS and I am deploying into OSE. Also I am using below dependencies in my project.

```
 "webpack": "^2.2.0",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
 "react": "^15.5.4",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
```

also I am running my project through below build script.

```
"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --history-api-fallback --content-base . "
```

Everything goes fine in OSE and Webpack is compiled successfully. But on accessing the url it shows "Invalid Host Header" on the webpage.

Could anyone help on this. Somewhat New in React.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 37):

At your webpack config, you could add [`disableHostCheck: true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck) at `devServer` configuration. For example,

```
devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Comment: This is not recommended as it introduces security issues. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887 for an explanation.

Comment: what is the recommended solution then? the link doesn't seem resolved

Comment: This solution is acceptable for local environment.

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of Webpack (I use v4) the `disableHostCheck` **is not available**, but the documentation suggests using `allowedHosts`. It worked for me.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
};
```

See [Webpack's devServer.allowedHosts](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts).

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain why this is happening.

**webpack-dev-server** has released *v2.4.3*.

Quoting their patch note:

> The Host header of the request have to match the listening adress or the host  provided in the public option.
> Make sure to provide correct values here.

They have also included [`disableHostCheck`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck) to turn this check off, **BUT**

> Only use it when you know what you do. Not recommended.

Comment: But why it is breaking with webpack version of 2.2.0??

Comment: Good question. My version from package.json was `^1.16.2`. Still broke it.

Comment: @BharatSewani it's put into a patch version due to the previous setup having security issues. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a & https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887.

Comment: @m_gol Thanks a lot for that! It actually reads _Maybe they read the release notes when it breaks._

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I read the article  so instead of doing disable host check : true we should pass 'public:www.xyz.com' in our npm start script?
"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --inline --history-api-fallback --public xyz.com --content-base . "
 where xyz.com is our server ip.
 Correct me if I am wrong @m_gol

Answer (score 2):

**Configuring the react target host will fix the "Invalid Host Header" error**

Find the [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of your react server, for example if your server's FQDN is:  my.devserver.com

Add the following line to your .env file:

```
HOST=my.devserver.com
```

Restart the react app and access it at http://my.devserver.com:3000/

If my.devserver.com needs to be accessible from other machines, add this line to your hosts file (/etc/hosts on Unix based systems):

```
0.0.0.0 my.devserver.com
```

Comment: When I use nginx + ssl locally - this solution  doesn't work. I'm using nginx as transparent proxy - and ...oh wait (maybe I need to change host file on my nginx container...) ... confusing....

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing this in combination with nginx proxy + ssl / and docker I needed to specify the HOST but also bespoke proxy var
https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/frontend/src/setupProxy.js

I basically needed to tell react both the HOST +
environment:

```
- REACT_APP_API_HOST=www.yourdomainhere.com
- HOST=frontend 


services:
  go:
    networks:
      - "quickstart"
    depends_on:
      - "frontend"
    image: "100418366104"
    ports: ["8000:8000"]

 
  frontend:
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_HOST=www.yourdomainhere.com # see above setupProxy.js file
      - HOST=frontend 
    networks:
      - "quickstart"
    image: "e478fc0620e6"
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
  nginx:
    networks:
      - "quickstart"
    build:
        dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
        context: .
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    depends_on:
        - frontend
networks:
  quickstart:
    name: quickstart
```

Answer (score 0):

change the host to 127.0.0.1 in build script.

`"build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1 --inline --history-api-fallback --content-base . "`